# Using the rep() function in R

Tags: r

I am using the `rep()` functon in R with a vector:

```
c("x","y")[rep(c(1,2,2,1), times=4)]
```

Its output is:

```
"x" "y" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y" "x"
```

I don't understand why it is repeating `x y y x` here.
If I use `rep(c(1,2,2,1), times=4)`, it will repeat `1 2 2 1` four times.

Why is it using `x` and `y` here?

Comment: Andrew Haynes answer provides a nice explanation for this case. For more details on indexing in R, take a look at the help file `?"["`. This is file is worth reading two or three times if you continue to use R.

Answer (score 9):

Your `rep()` code produces the vector:

`> rep(c(1,2,2,1),times=4)
 [1] 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1`

You can reference the elements in the vector `c("x","y")` by using their index, e.g:

`> c("x","y")[1]
[1] "x"`

provides the element at position 1 in your vector, which in this case is `"x"`.

You can also reference this element multiple times by using a vector of indices, e.g:

`> c("x","y")[c(1,1,1,1,1)]
[1] "x" "x" "x" "x" "x"`

returns the element at position one in your vector 5 times.

So when you supply `R` with `c("x","y")[rep(c(1,2,2,1), times=4)]`, which is the same as  `c("x","y")[c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1)]`, what you return is the same pattern, but are replacing those values with the elements in the vector at those indices.

So instead of returning 1,2,2,1 repeated 4 times, you are returning the 1st,2nd, 2nd, and 1st elements of your vector repeated 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

`rep(x, ...)`

Do you need to bring what you want to repeat inside the rep bracket.

What output are you looking for specifically?

```
rep(c("x", "y", "y", "x") , times = 4)
```

gives you

```
"x" "y" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y" "x"
```